# What does an empty auto-reply email from a potential supervisor mean?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, email

I emailed a professor asking about a graduate student position. Immediately, I received an empty email titled auto-reply.
What does that mean? Can it be an indication that I won't be able to reach her via this email address?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with academia, it’s a [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about)-type question about generic email issues. Voted to close.

Comment: You're right. My bad. I tried to delete it, but I can't. @DanRomik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means something went wrong. It could be "an indication that I won't be able to reach her via this email address" or it could be something else. You should check the department webpage to see if it is the correct address. If so, wait a week or so and try again.

Comment: Or the respondent just set up an auto reply and forgot to add any content. It won't be noticed until pointed out, I guess. It is fairly common to hit send, for example, before you finish your composition.